# Как передать "text" в C используя Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, препроцессор

Есть фаил BoardConfig.mk
В нем есть команда

```
TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM := mt6572
```

Мы берём это значение в Android.mk так

```
init_options += -Dold_kernel=$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM)
```

и передаем его в init.cpp

```
{ "ro.boot.hardware",   "ro.hardware",   old_kernel, },
```

В итоге мы имеем:

```
{ "ro.boot.hardware",   "ro.hardware",   mt6572, },
```

Как сделать так, что бы передаваемое значение заключалась в "" ?
То есть что бы получалась такая строка:

```
{ "ro.boot.hardware",   "ro.hardware",   "mt6572", },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо просто в Android.mk изменить строку на:

```
init_options += -Dold_kernel=\"$(TARGET_BOARD_PLATFORM)\"
```

Comment: Забавный психологический момент - меня так зашорил предыдущий вопрос ТС, в котором категорически отвергалось взятие в кавычки на уровне определения, что я даже не подумал об этом варианте :)

Answer (score 2):

В .cpp-файле добавляем макроопределение типа

```
#define STR(x) #x
```

и пишем

```
{"ro.boot.hardware", "ro.hardware", STR(old_kernel), },
```

Все.

Comment: Это просто обрабатывает как "old_kernel" , без возможности изменения на "mt6572"

Comment: Определите `-Dold_kernel=чему-то-там`. Без этого, понятно, `old_kernel` ни во что не раскрывается, оставаясь `old_kernel`. И еще - почитайте литературу о макросах.